# React with redux-persist when navigate the UI is stuck

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga, redux-persist

When I navigate through the app the UI is stuck although the url changes.

I would like to integrate redux-persist on my current app but it eventually drove me to a strange bug to me.

Note: I use also the redux-saga as middleware on creating the store.

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web and AsyncStorage for react-native

import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";
import rootSaga from '../sagas/index'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const middleware = applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  {},
  composeEnhancers(middleware)
)

export const persistor = persistStore(store)

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

export default store

window.store = store
```

When I comment in the Persist Gate component then the navigation works as intended.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import registerServiceWorker from "./js/registerServiceWorker";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import store, { persistor } from './js/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </Router >,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

I hope I made myself clear!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the router in persist?

Comment: @Colin thank you for the help! You are right. I had to wrap router in persist..

Comment: Cool! I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your `Router` with the `PersistGate`. The order of these higher order components matters for React Router. The way you have it now, when you change the url it's not triggering a re-render, so swapping the order should fix the issue.